# Is there a way to create a video, and store it as a Buffer in Node.JS without saving it as a file?

Tags: node.js, image, video, buffer

I'm in a bit of an odd situation where I have several images (currently stored as base64 strings in buffers), and I'd like to be able to combine them into a video. The catch is that I need this video file in a buffer, and if I have to write files to the disk, and then read them back as a buffer, the program will run too slowly.

I've looked into several other posts on stackoverflow, and libraries that I've found online. However, everything that I've managed to find uses FFMPEG, which would require me to write everything to a file.

For the sake of clarity, what I'm essentially looking for is something that would be able to make the following pseudocode work:

```js
var frames = .... //I have this already

var videoEncoder = new VideoEncoder();

for(var frame in frames)
{
    videoEncoder.add(frames[frame]);
}

var buffer = videoEncoder.toBuffer();
```